# Формирование турнирной таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Хочу сформировать футбольную  турнирную таблицу на основе следующих данных: 
games - расписания только матчей без результата, goals - результаты матчей.
Хочу формировать данные на лету в формате:

```
|Команда|Количество матчей|Победы|Поражения|Ничья|Голы|Очки|
```

Возможно так сделать в моей структуре данных, и что посоветуете изменить?

```
 CREATE TABLE `teams` (
      `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

 // расписание
    CREATE TABLE `games` (
        `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `team1_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `team2_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `tournament_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `published` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
        `match_date` DATE NOT NULL,
        `match_time` TIME NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )

 // результаты игр
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `goals` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `team_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `game_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `goals` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
```

Comment: Если результаты определяются исключительно по количеству goals (это так ?), то особых проблем в структуре я не вижу. Кроме разве что избыточности, в games не нужны поля team1_id, team2_id. Правда тогда в goals записи надо будет добавить сразу, разрешив NULL в поле goals, что бы отличать ситуацию, когда данных еще нет и 0 голов. И возможно стоит подумать как исключить ситуацию, что в goals забыли добавить записи или добавили более 2х команд. первое похоже полностью на совести приложения, второе можно решить номером команды 1,2 с запретом других номеров и уникальностью game_id,номер

Comment: По-моему, таблица результатов вообще не нужна, результат вполне можно хранить в таблице игр. Заодно не придётся возиться с реализацией контроля целостности по таблице игр, и упростится получение результата игры.

Comment: @Akina Да, согласен, это упростит структуру, сделав запросы чуть менее тривиальными, но потенциально более быстрыми. По крайней мере до тех пор, пока не появится какая нибудь еще информация о команде в игре, которую надо будет хранить

Comment: *появится какая нибудь еще информация о команде в игре, которую надо будет хранить* Да, тогда действительно возникнет необходимость в таблице, где-то аналогичной таблице `goals` (её надо будет назвать `game_comments`). Но вот ради исключительно количества заколоченных командой в матче шайб/мячей/прочего - не нужна она. Ведь в показанной структуре даже просто получить результат матча - уже определённый выверт потребуется. А если это хоккей? даже факта победы по полученному из таблиц счёту недостаточно, чтобы понять, сколько очков получит команда - два или три...

Comment: Если добавить в таблицу games поля goal, то тогда будут сплошные NULL (так как игра не состоялась) - а это плохо. Вот и вынес в отдельную таблицу результаты. 
ps: результаты будут только футбола.